# Database connection through one of the scan ip is failing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, ojdbc

Oracle Database connection through one of the scan ip is failing.

- nslookup of scanhost name returns 3 IPs
- Able to ping all 3 IPs
- Able to telnet to each of the 3 IP and DB port separately

But if i make a connection to DB using individual scan ips using jdbc , only 2 are connecting to Database.
what would be problem.?

I am not a DBA and i have access only to SQL developer and read access.
It is a 2 node RAC database

Comment: There could be an issue with the SCAN Listener configuration or the database's ability to register with it. You will need to get in touch with the DBA to resolve it.

Comment: DBA is saying all fine or they could not spot the issue. what should i ask exactly should i ask them to check the status of all 3 scan listeners?

Comment: Yes, all three. They will need to run the `lsnrctl status` command from the host that each is actually running on to confirm the database is registered correctly. Are you getting back a specific error message? Pass that on to them as well.

Comment: this was the message "ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service  "when trying to connect from 2 of the scan ips individually.   so  should i ask to  run the lsnrctl status from all the 3 hosts/Ips separately ? or from the 2 hosts where the DB RAC is running?

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same but in our case we have checked lsnrctl output and all seems fine. Also the scan ip which is not connecting from one client server is connecting from a different clinet server.